# Taxonomy in a review paper

Tags: literature-review, acm

I submitted a Review paper to a journal where the review committee reported

> Author did not make Taxonomy of the his review

I do not understand their need. After searching the questions in this forum, I came across the question regarding ACM 2012 Taxonomy. Are the reviewers asking for this ACM 2012 Taxonomy or something else?

Comment: It is probably best to ask this question directly to the editor or associate editor that sent you the review decisions. Their interpretation of the comment is what matters most.

Comment: Right, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the reviewers were requesting that you include a set of “Index Terms” or “Keywords” for your paper, e.g., for IEEE, pulled from the list of [IEEE Taxonomy](https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/taxonomy_v101.pdf) or [Standardized Keywords](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/create-the-text-of-your-article/ieee-standardized-keywords/).

Excerpts the second link:

> Help readers find your article quickly by using the right IEEE standardized keywords.
>
> using the right keywords in your article can make your article more easily and reliably discoverable—which leads to a broader readership for your article.